# List items is some indices first in Elasticsearch search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm scraping few sites and relisting their products, each site has their own index in Elasticsearch. Some sites have affiliate programs, I'd like to list those first in my search results.

Is there a way for me to "boost" results from a certain index?

Should I write a field `hasAffiliate: true` into ES when I'm scraping and then [boosting the query clauses](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html) that have that has that value? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Using `boost` could be difficult to guarantee that they appear first in the search. According to the official guide:

> Practically, there is no simple formula for deciding on the “correct”
>   boost value for a particular query clause. It’s a matter of
>   try-it-and-see. Remember that boost is just one of the factors
>   involved in the relevance score

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html

It depends on the type of queries you are doing, but here you have other couple of options:

- A [score function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) with weights: could be a more predictable option.
- Simply using a [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) by `hasAffiliate` (the easiest one). 
  Note: Not sure if sorting by boolean field is possible, in that case you could set hasAffiliate mapping as integer `byte` (smallest one), setting it as `1` when true.

Comment: Doing sorting after the search has done is also solid option, but it would be cool to do that work in the lower level. Thanks!